# PHP $_FILES Array suddenly empty

Tags: php, upload, centos6

I have this form running on first page:

```
<form class="frmFrameSubmit" name="frmFrameSubmit" action="checkout.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  type="file" name="inpUploadFile" class="inpUploadFile" style="display:none;" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
    <input name="inpFrameWidth" class="inpFrameWidth" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input name="inpFrameHeight" class="inpFrameHeight" type="hidden" value="0">
</form>
```

and this php code running on the other page:

```
if(isset( $_POST['inpFrameWidth'] )) {

    $aExtraInfo = getimagesize($_FILES["inpUploadFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    $sImage = "data:" . $aExtraInfo["mime"] . ";base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["inpUploadFile"]["tmp_name"]));

***********************************
rest of the code
***********************************

}
else{
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit(1);
}
```

It has been working for weeks and suddenly, I get this error in php error log:

```
[10-Jun-2014 10:38:48] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: inpUploadFile in checkout.php on line6
```

What I tried:

- Verifying file_uploads, post_max_size , upload_max_filesize but they are still on good values
- Clearing tmp files ; $sudo rm -rf /tmp/*

This is running on a dev server with centos6

Comment: if this was working for a while and this problem is caused suddenly , it`s better contact to the server adminstrator and ask for changes . maybe they`ve changed some configs or updates ...

Comment: are you sure it's empty? `var_dump($_FILES)` shows `array(0) { }`?

Comment: yes, var_dump($_FILES) gives me : array(0) {}

Answer (score 0):

After trying to output the content of $_FILES, I realised that my form was submiting(the url was changing) but that the content wasn't reloading. I could still see the whole html + ressources content of the first page. However I had the output of my other page as a response in a POST request in firebug just like when you do an AJAX call.

I was really wondering what I changed for my whole website to go crazy.

Then I realised I added jquery mobile last night for testing purpose on mobile widgets and removing it fixed all my problems.

I guess Jquery Mobile was replacing my input file with some custom element.